# arrow rule of three

Tags: tikz-arrows

How can we draw an arrow illustrating the rule of three like this:
[image]

If we have for example:

f(x_a) = y_a

f(x_b) = y_b

the arrow would start from y_a, go to f(x_b), then f(x_a) to end at y_b

Comment: Have a look at `tikzmark` tag, this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve that with `tikzmark` library. You may find more informations about how to use it if you want to adjust it the way you like. Just search follow `tikzmark` tagged posts here.

[image: arrow rule of three]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \tikzmarknode{A}{f(x_a)}=\tikzmarknode{B}{y_a}
    \]
    \vspace{5pt}
    \[
    \tikzmarknode{C}{f(x_b)}=\tikzmarknode{D}{y_b}
    \]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \draw[cyan,line width=1pt,->] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A.south) ([yshift=7pt]D.north) ([yshift=5pt]C.north) (B.south west)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!